# Do shrinkage estimators work when the amount of noise is correlated with the true value?

Tags: regularization

In a normal means model, I understand that say $X \sim N(\theta,\Sigma)$, the canonical result is that the James-Stein shrinkage estimator dominates the max-likelihood estimator. But what if the elements of $\theta$, $\theta_{i}$, are correlated with the elements of $\Sigma,\Sigma_{i}$? For example, if the true value of each element $\theta_{i}$ is a function of $\Sigma_{i}$, e.g. the more noise there is for element $i$ the smaller the true value $\theta_{i}$. Then does the James-Stein shrinkage estimator still dominate the max-likelihood estimator? And if so, what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you clarify whether $\theta$ is fixed or random in the model you want to discuss?

Comment: thanks @eric_kernfeld! I can start with $\theta$ fixed. So we know that for some $i$'s the observed $X$'s are noisier, but also that their corresponding $\theta_{i}$'s will be lower.

Comment: In James-Stein estimation, the parameter $\theta$ is constant, not random. Same thing with $\Sigma$.